# Throwing a std::out_of_range exception. "expected type-specifier"

Tags: c++, exception, std

I am making a class that should be a very poor `string`, but I have this issue with the `at` methods.

MyString.h

```
char at(unsigned int i) const throw(std::out_of_range);
char& at(unsigned int i) throw(std::out_of_range);
```

MyString.cpp

```
char MyString::at(unsigned int i) const throw(std::out_of_range) {
    if (mylength_ == 0 || i < 0 || i > mylength_ - 1)
        throw std::out_of_range("nopenope");
    return string_[i];
}

char& MyString::at(unsigned int i) throw(std::out_of_range) {
    if (mylength_ == 0 || i < 0 || i > mylength_ - 1)
        throw std::out_of_range("nopenope");
    return string_[i];
}
```

Comment: At which line you get this message? And have you included stdexcept?

Comment: Prefer std::size_t over unsigned int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you did not include header `<stdexcept>`